# Django ORM in Views - How can I join multiple tables (models)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I am new to Django and went through the docs but still can't find a solution to my problem.
I checked several tutorials regarding ORM and how to use it in my views but maybe I landed on basic queries. If any can recommend a tutorial regarding ORM and manipulating ORM or some ORM exercises to practice it would be much appreciated.
Let's get back to the point:
I need to create a view (my homepage - superidlist view) that sends the needed data to my template to be shown on a collapsible menu.
I have 4 models for now. SuperID, ClientAccount, Entity, Transaction. The collapsible menu needs to show the entity_super_id, the accounts number for each entity and the transactions made for each account.
How should write the view to show the specific transactions for each specific account on dropdown and not all the transactions.  I will post the models.py, the view and part of the template

```
models.py:

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import widgets
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models import Q


class SuperIDQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(super_id__icontains=query) |
                         Q(account_name__icontains=query) |
                         Q(full_name__icontains=query)
                         )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()  # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs


class SuperIDManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SuperIDQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  # useful to build a reusable search

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)


class SuperID(models.Model):
    super_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Full name', max_length=50, blank=True)
    objects = SuperIDManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("super_id", "account_name")
        ordering = ("super_id", "account_name")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % self.super_id  # , self.account_name, self.full_name


class ClientAccountQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(client_account_name__icontains=query) |
                         Q(client_full_name__icontains=query) |
                         Q(account_type__icontains=query) |
                         Q(account_creation_date__icontains=query)
                         )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()  # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs


class ClientAccountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ClientAccountQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  # useful to build a reusable search

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)


class ClientAccount(models.Model):
    ACCOUNTS_TYPES = [
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('joint', 'Joint'),
    ]
    client_super_id = models.ForeignKey(SuperID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # , related_name='client_account_super_id')
    client_account_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='account_name')
    # client_account_name = models.ForeignKey(SuperID, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_account_code',
    #                                       blank=True, default='00000000')
    client_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ACCOUNTS_TYPES)
    account_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Creation Date', auto_now_add=True)
    objects = ClientAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % self.client_super_id


class EntityQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(entity_account_name__icontains=query) |
                         Q(entity_id__icontains=query) |
                         Q(entity_full_name__icontains=query) |
                         Q(entity_creation_date__icontains=query) |
                         Q(entity_type__icontains=query)
                         )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()  # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs


class EntityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EntityQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  # useful to build a reusable search

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)


class Entity(models.Model):
    ENTITY_TYPES = [
        ('individual', 'Individual'),
        ('signatory', 'Signatory'),
        ('power of attorney', 'POA'),
    ]
    entity_super_id = models.ForeignKey(ClientAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # , related_name='entity_super_id')
    entity_account_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Entity_account_name')
    # entity_account_name = models.ForeignKey(ClientAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entity_account_code',
    #                                       default='00000000')
    entity_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Entity ID', default=0)
    entity_full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Full Name', max_length=30)
    entity_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Creation Date', auto_now_add=True)
    entity_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ENTITY_TYPES)
    objects = EntityManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % self.entity_super_id
        # , self.entity_id, self.entity_full_name, self.entity_creation_date, self.entity_type)


class TransactionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(transaction_id__icontains=query) |
                         Q(transaction_number__icontains=query) |
                         Q(transaction_type__icontains=query) |
                         Q(transaction_amount__icontains=query) |
                         Q(transaction_currency__icontains=query) |
                         Q(transaction_status__icontains=query)  # |
                         # Q(transaction_date__icontains=query)
                         )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()  # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs


class TransactionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return TransactionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  # useful to build a reusable search

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    TRANSACTION_TYPES = [
        ('CASH', 'CASH'),
        ('TRANSFER', 'TRANSFER'),
        ('CHECK', 'CHECK'),
        ('TRADE', 'TRADE'),
    ]
    TRANSACTION_CURRENCIES = [
        ('USD', 'USD'),
        ('LEBANESE POUND', 'LEBANESE POUND'),
        ('EURO', 'EURO'),
    ]
    TRANSACTION_STATUS = [
        ('APPROVED', 'APPROVED'),
        ('PENDING', 'PENDING'),
        ('REJECTED', 'REJECTED'),
    ]
    transaction_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Transaction id', default=0)
    transaction_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='Transaction Number', max_length=10, blank=True)
    transaction_account = models.ForeignKey(ClientAccount, verbose_name='Account Name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Transaction Type', max_length=30, choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES)
    transaction_amount = models.CharField(verbose_name='Amount', max_length=20)
    transaction_currency = models.CharField(verbose_name='Currency', max_length=30, choices=TRANSACTION_CURRENCIES)
    transaction_status = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status', max_length=30, choices=TRANSACTION_STATUS)
    transaction_status_reason = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status Reason', max_length=200, blank=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Transaction Date', default=timezone.now)
    objects = TransactionManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % self.transaction_number


View:

def superid_list(request):
   super_ids = SuperID.objects.order_by('super_id', 'account_name')
   entities = Entity.objects.all()
   trans = Transaction.objects.all()
   paginator = Paginator(super_ids, 3)  # 3 posts in each page
   page = request.GET.get('page')
   try:
      super_ids = paginator.page(page)
   except PageNotAnInteger:  # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
      super_ids = paginator.page(1)
   except EmptyPage:  # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
      super_ids = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
   return render(request, 'AMLNEW/superid_list.html',
        context={'super_ids': super_ids, 'entities': entities, 'trans': trans, 'page': page})


Template block:

{% block entity_dropdown %}

    {% for ent in entities %}
     <ul>
       <button type="button" class="collapsible"><strong>{{ ent.entity_super_id }}</strong></button>
       <div class="content">
          <button type="button" class="collapsible">{{ ent.entity_account_name }}</button>
            <div class="content">
            <ul>

                    {% for tran in trans %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="transactions/{{ tran.transaction_account }}">{{ tran.transaction_number }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
     </ul>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I am getting this: a list of all transactions since I couldn't manage to write a normal query to show only the specific transactions of a specific account. Check below link please for image.
[How to show specific transactions related to an account and not all transactions in general?][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJSwC.jpg
```

Comment: How do you "*link*" transactions to the user. What path of `ForeignKey`s/`ManyToManyField`s/... eventually leads to the user object?

Comment: I thought of linking the entity of which the user accounts belongs to the clientaccount then to link the specific clientaccount to the transactions. But how should I write this? I am getting totally lost there.
My model is based on: SuperID -> Can have multiple accounts; Each account can have multiple Entities; Each entity can have multiple SuperIDs and so on...

Comment: These 2 views were used to get the entity by superID and the transaction for a specific account:

Comment: def entities_by_sid(request, pk):
    entities = Entity.objects.all()
    trans = Transaction.objects.all()

    entity_of = SuperID.objects.filter(super_id__exact=pk)
    for ent in entity_of:
        entity_of = ent.clientaccount_set.filter(client_super_id__super_id=pk)
        for en in entity_of:
            entity_of = en.entity_set.all()
    return render(request, 'AMLNEW/entity_by_sid.html', context={'entity_of': entity_of, 'entities': entities, 'trans': trans})

Comment: def transactions_detail(request, pk):
    entities = Entity.objects.all()
    transa = Transaction.objects.all()
    global client_variable
    acc_sid = ClientAccount.objects.filter(client_account_name=pk)
    for trans in acc_sid:
        client_variable = trans.transaction_set.all()
    return render(request, 'AMLNEW/transactions_detail.html',context={'acc_sid': acc_sid, 'client_variable': client_variable, 'entities': entities,'transa': transa})